# Resolving promises in a loop

Tags: typescript, promise

Can someone please help me understand why resolving promises in a loop only works if I access the loop variable?  For example, this logs 5 times:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    this.getData()
        .then(() => console.log("gotData " + i));
}
```

but this only logs once:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    this.getData()
        .then(() => console.log("gotData"));
}
```

when getData() is defined as:

```
private getData(): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

What is the correct way to handle promises in a loop?

Comment: I think this is bug (may be concerning loop optimisations). I just have no typescrypt but only want to know how it work if rewrite `for` loop with `while` with incremet like this `while(++i<5)`?

Comment: Take a look at your console. Do you see at the far right of the output a `5`? The browser console collapses multiple outputs to one if the are equal. And of course it can't do that if the text is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matthias already said, browser's collapse console output that is the same and show a count indicator. The code behaves exactly the same. Anyway:

---

If you want to sequentially resolve `Promise`s you have to do something like this:

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce(
  (acc, i) => {
    acc.then(() => console.log(i));
    return acc;
  }, 
  Promise.resolve()
);
```

If ordering does not matter you can use `Promise.all`. If you want more info on the topic just search StackOverflow. There is plenty ;)

Comment: I think this may be a bug in Chrome.  I am aware of the feature to group identical logs, but it is not happening in this case - in other cases it does.  Tested in Firefox and that works correctly.